# Launch my Android app using hardware button Home and Lock button(hardware button)

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to open application when taking screenshot from device.

Comment: Not sure that is possible

Comment: You ask for one thing in the topic and one thing in the body of your question.  What is it you actually want?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a straightforward way to detect screenshot. ([Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75247) already filled)
What you can do is to use a [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to monitor any change inside the `Screenshots` directory.

Comment: thanksFor the give me suggestionsit will work perfectly

Comment: I have small problem when i open the app at taking screenshot at it open one time, but not open second time.

Comment: I would love to help you, can you please create new question with code attached? and tag me, @MayankPatel

Comment: this is th link when i upload my code for opening the app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092557/issue-in-app-open-with-fileobserver