# issue in app open with fileObserver

Tags: android, fileobserver

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+ File.separator + "Screenshots";
FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(path, FileObserver.CREATE) {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(mIntent);
    }
};
fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Comment: uses-permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and uses-permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: i have not problem without path but when i send path from one page to other page that time problem accure

Comment: same time file obsarver not create(not work)

Comment: Complite this with Hendler